# Nios 2 Gen 2 Extra Exceptions Information

Tags: exception, nios

I have created a design in Qsys in which I'm using a Nios II Gen2 processor. While running the software for that hardware in the Nios II Eclipse IDE, I'm getting an exception but the cause of the exception cannot be determined. I found out that I needed to enable extra exceptions information or include MPU or MLU to get exception information. There is not option available to enable extra exceptions information in Nios II Gen 2 like there was in Nios II Classic processor. Also enabling MLU or MPU doesn't produce any extra exceptions information and the cause of the exception in still unknown. How can I find out what is causing this exception without having to revert to Nios II Classis processor?